# Cypress No commands were issued in this test is shown but the test do have commands

Tags: cypress

I'm just starting with automated testing with cypress and I have done a little suite for a smoke test but when I run all the suite some of the test are showing "No commands were issued in this test" and when I run only that file it run without any issue

Cypress.json only have the base url and default timeout

```
it("T39043 Calculadora de cartones", () => {
cy.get('[placeholder="¿Qué buscas?"]').type("ponky");
cy.get(
  'a[href="/product/000027981/Pastel%20PONKY%20A&A%20Est%20x%205%20und"]'
).click({ force: true });

cy.get("cx-page-slot.Summary")
  .should("be.visible")
  .within(() => {
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "0 unidades");
    cy.get("cx-icon.icon-plus").eq(0).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("input[type=number]").eq(0).should("have.value", 1);
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "12 unidades");
  });

cy.get('[placeholder="¿Qué buscas?"]').clear().type("Salsa tártara");
cy.get(
  'a[href="/product/00003294/Salsa%20t%C3%A1rtara%20LA%20CONSTANCIA%20x90g"]'
)
  .eq(1)
  .click({ force: true });

cy.get("cx-page-slot.Summary")
  .should("be.visible")
  .within(() => {
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "0 unidades");
    cy.get("cx-icon.icon-plus").eq(0).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("input[type=number]").eq(0).should("have.value", 1);
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "72 unidades");

    cy.get("cx-icon.icon-plus").eq(1).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("input[type=number]").eq(1).should("have.value", 3);
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "75 unidades");

    cy.get("cx-icon.icon-minus").eq(0).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("cx-icon.icon-plus").eq(1).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("input[type=number]").eq(1).should("have.value", 6);
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "6 unidades");
  });

cy.get('[placeholder="¿Qué buscas?"]').clear().type("Snaky salado");
cy.get('a[href="/product/0000797/Pasaboca%20SNACKY%20salado%20x40g"]')
  .eq(1)
  .click({ force: true });

cy.get("cx-page-slot.Summary")
  .should("be.visible")
  .within(() => {
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "0 unidades");
    cy.get("cx-icon.icon-plus").eq(0).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("input[type=number]").eq(0).should("have.value", 1);
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "36 unidades");

    cy.get("cx-icon.icon-plus").eq(1).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("input[type=number]").eq(1).should("have.value", 5);
    cy.get("span.total-quantity").should("contain", "41 unidades");
  });
```

});

[image]

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: What command are you using to run the entire suite? What command are you using to only run only one spec file? Can you post your entire test that you're running?

Comment: Why does the screenshot show a partial line at the bottom?

Comment: @agoff It looks like stackoverflow don't allow me to add more images and related to the command I'm using the visual interface and also npm cypress run

Comment: You can add the code directly, which is more useful IMO.

Comment: @agoff you're right, I just did it

Comment: Hi @Thomas, were you able to resolve this? If so, can you please tell me how?